# Make div stretch to fit td height

Tags: html, css, html-table, stretch

Hi I have this code,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="the-div">h:100%</div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="the-div-w-height">h:100px</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

with this style,

```
.the-div
{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.the-div-w-height
{
  height : 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

I want to make the red div stretch inside the td, the other div can change in height according to the content, the first div shall stretch with the table

Thank you

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442747/making-a-div-inherit-the-height-of-parent-td-using-only-css

Comment: [**here you go**](http://jsfiddle.net/3k6kq/1/)

Comment: @NoobEditor OK in Chrome, KO in Firefox (also needs `td { height: 100% }` I guess)

Comment: @gillesc Unrelated to table imho, which is a different case especially in Firefox

Comment: I this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588947/have-a-link-fill-div-vertically/24589041#24589041) is related.

Comment: @NoobEditor I don't want to make the table stretch on the whole screen

Comment: @estshy this did the trick, I'll try it and hope it has no further implications

Answer (score 3):

Adding `height: 100%` on parents `table` and `td`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByjIv

```
table {
  height: 100%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100%;
}
.the-div
{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.the-div-w-height
{
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the height of the table or the td, this will stretch the table to fit the whole page

Comment: ?? It doesn't change anything to the height of the table (check the Codepen). But in the 2nd comment to your question (from gillesc), that's what Pete's solution does.