# CSS - <div> height

Tags: html, css

EDITED:

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div class="div-table-row">
        <div class="div-table-first-col">
            <div>11:00</div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-col">
            <div style="height: 11"></div>
            <div class="appuntamentoContainer">
                <div class="appuntamento" style="height: 25px">11:12 - 12:35</div> //--> need to stretch to bottom
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-col">
            <div style="height: 0"></div>
            <div class="appuntamento">11:00 - 11:45</div>
            <div class="appuntamento">11:00 - 12:00</div>
            <div class="appuntamento">11:45 - 12:30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-col">
            <div style="height: "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="div-table-col">
            <div style="height: "></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.div-table div.appuntamento {
    background-color: #f3f2de;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #d7dde6;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.div-table {
    display:table;         
    width:auto;         
}
.div-table-row{
    display:table-row;
    width:auto;
    clear:both;
    height: 45px;
}
.div-table-col {
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column;         
    width:154px;
}
.div-table-row .div-table-col{
    border-left: 1px solid #d7dde6;
    border-right: 1px solid #d7dde6;
    border-top: 1px solid #d7dde6;
    min-height: 44px;         
}
.div-table-first-col {
    float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
    display:table-column; 
    text-align: right;
    width: 45px;
}
.div-table-first-col div{
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

[Here the fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/emaborsa/1cejh0dL/2/)

[image]

Notice the vertical borders. On the left side how it actually is, on the right side how it should. How do i stretch the div to the bottom?

Comment: You should take a loot at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110915/is-a-div-inside-a-td-a-bad-idea

Comment: can you please share a snap as to what you exactly want?

Comment: What is `<div style="height: 11">` supposed to achieve?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1cejh0dL/4/ ..Is this what you wanted?

Comment: See it  again..Now should work

Comment: Are you kidding? I should set a fixed heigth to the div?

Comment: But thats what you have done in your code as well..`<div style="height: 11">`

Comment: That's a spacer, an inner cell. The outer cells have to be dynamic.

Comment: Changed my previous answer. Check that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) layout model. Just add `display: flex;` to `.div-table-row`, and remove any `float` or `display` property.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cejh0dL/10/).

Answer (score 1):

add height: 100% on parents table and td.

```
table {
  height: 100%;
}
td {
  height: 100%;
}
```

for reference look here: [Make div stretch to fit td height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594742/make-div-stretch-to-fit-td-height)

Comment: ...not really. I don't want to stretch it to 100%, but to the bottom of the td.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for some dynamic behaviour:

jQuery

```
var a=$(".second").outerHeight();

$(".first").height(a);
$(".third").height(a);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1cejh0dL/6/

Comment: Sorry didn't get you.Whar disappears?

Comment: Man what is the problem in this one. I mean you wanted it to stretch full. So I gave it the height of what is there in the second `div-table-col`. Atleast thats what your picture suggests

Comment: I did not ask to do it with jQuery...i want to do it with css. What if i have 15 rows and 6 columns? should i set all of them using jQuery?

Comment: This code would be applicable in that scenario too. You can give same class to `div-table-col` divs that do not have the maximum height and then can set the height of those divs to the height of maximum `div-table-col`. Watch this fiddle on a full screen.  https://jsfiddle.net/1cejh0dL/7/